# return only value from a function of a shell script to another shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

I have one script name `check.ksh` which will check some functionality and having different functions for that:

```
!/bin/ksh
print "start"
val1=$1
val2=$2
func=$3

checkfunc() {
 if [[ $val1 != $val2 ]]
 then
         print "argument differs"
         exit 0
 else
         print "argument same"
         exit 1
 fi
 }
anotherfunc() {

print "blah blah"
}
 $func 2&1> testlog.log
 print "end"
```

and another  wrapper script name `wrapper.ksh` which will use as a wrapper script of `check.ksh`:

```
#!/bin/ksh

wfunc() {
check.sh $1 $2 $3
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && printf "different argument passed" || printf "same argument passed"
}

wfunc $1 $2 $3
```

when I run `./wrapper.sh test1 test1 checkfunc` its should print the output as `"same argument passed"` as the called script `check.sh` ***exited with 1***

but always I am getting $? as 0

I have tried to print some value or using return but same issue, can we return only the output from the function to the `wrapper.ksh`

**note** : I cannot remove the print and other things in `check.sh` I can only edit the content of `checkfunc()` in the `check.sh`

Comment: In your wrapper.sh, you're calling wfunc without any argument. The argument within the function are the ones with which you called the function, not the script. Basically you're calling check.sh without any arguments, it prints "end" then exit with 0.

Comment: I have done that but still not working, its not the problem, anyway the script is running as I checked after setting `set -vx`

Comment: Actually I think you're trying to use && and || wrong. You're trying to translate something that should an if/then/else, but it won't work. The way it's written now is that if $? is 0 then execute the whole statement after &&. If it's not, don't bother and continue, which is exactly what your script is doing.

Comment: I have tried with if else also, but no luck

Comment: In check.sh use "$func 2>testlog.log 1>&2", works in my test after that.

Comment: yes its working, but m wondering is there any consequence if I change that because `check.ksh` is big script, and I dont want to change anything other than my function `checkfunc()`. and why its not working with `$func 2&1> testlog.log`

Comment: Well with your syntax, $func 2& will start the function $func with parameter 2 and in background, then fd 1 is redirected to testlog.log. And that's why check.sh is printing "end" with this syntax.